# SceneKit SCNLookAtConstraint could not overload init

Tags: xcode, swift, scenekit

In the example project of `sceneKit` I am trying to make the camera look at the ship object which I have offset from the center. But for some reason I am unable to do it.

I use the following code to look at the ship. but it still gives as error:

> Could not find an overload for init.

I am using **swift** to code.

```
cameraNode.constraints = SCNLookAtConstraint(ship)
```

pls help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following in autocomplete, which looks promising:

[image: SCNLookAtConstraint(target:)]

This is the Swift form of the ObjC factory method `+lookAtConstraintWithTarget:`.

In general, there are three easy ways to find out how an ObjC factory method (like `+[NSFoo fooWithBar:]`) translates to a Swift initializer (like `init(bar:)`, which you call with the syntax `NSFoo(bar: heresABar)`):

- Type the class name into a Swift file, and an open paren, and autocomplete should show you the set of acceptable initializers
- Type the class name into a Swift file and command-click it to see the auto-generated Swift interface for that class (based on the ObjC header), including initializer declarations
- Look at the [documentation for a class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNLookAtConstraint_Class/index.html) online or in Xcode, and you'll see both ObjC and Swift declarations for each API.

Comment: I have different combinations, like(I know it is not supposed to be like this, but I am trying different things).
 
cameraNode.constraints = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: ship). 

I still get the same error cOuld not find an overload for init.

The documentation doesnt show ussage only syntax. And I tried looking at the examples and presentations from WWDC and it is all in Obj-C

Comment: As @mnuages notes, the `constraints` property expects an array, so passing it a single constraint will cause a compile error. (In this case, a slightly misleading one.) Sorry, I missed the bracket in my screenshot: it should be `cameraNode.constraints = [ SCNLookAtConstraint(target: ship) ]`

Comment: Thanks that worked. :). But it is not doing exactly what I thought it would. When the scene starts it still points to the ship if I make it look at an otherobject say there. When I double click on the screen it looks at the sphere. Strange!!

ANd thanks to mnuages. It is just that the syntax in the apple docs didnt mention that it needs an array. Also how woould it work if I gave it 10 things to look at??!??!...

Comment: Looks to me like the [`constraints`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNNode/constraints) declaration in the docs says it takes `[AnyObject]` — the brackets denote an array type. As for the constraints not doing what you expect, that'd be best served by another question (containing more info about your scene).

Comment: oh ok. I saw anyobject and sort of ignored. Will be mindful of it next time. 

I will ask a separate question.  thx again

Comment: Also, regarding multiple constraints: they get applied in order, so the last one in the array "wins". Remember there are different kinds of constraints, and each can have a reduced `influenceFactor`, so you can have situations where multiple constraints matter.

Comment: `NSArray` properties in ObjC get imported to Swift as `[AnyObject]` because the compiler doesn't have a way of knowing they should be more specific. I'm sure this one would be `[SCNConstraint]` if it could.

Comment: Ok got it. Ya it would be nice it said [SCNConstraint] :)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of setup works for me, obviously you're better off not just unwrapping the node in case it doesn't exist, but it gives the general idea.

```
let targetNode = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("nodeName", recursively: false)    
let constraint               = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: targetNode!)
cameraNode?.constraints = [constraint]
```

Comment: ya that works too. But I didnt realize that it was expecting an array. That was the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a look-at constraint with +lookAtConstraintWithTarget:.
Also note that the `constraints` property expects an array.

Comment: I am using swift so there is no lookAtConstraintWithTarget that is in Obj-C. Also it doesnt expect an array, it expects an SCNNode.

Comment: that's a bug in the Swift bridge that automatically converts Objective-C headers. You should file a bug. The `constraints` property does expect an array. The constraint constructor expects a node.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way. You could probably write some objective-c code (that calls the initializer) with the corresponding swift bridge.

Comment: Ya, it could be a bug or an omission. I command clicked on the SCNLookATConstraint and the init(target) function is a convenience init... there is no regular init constructor which sets the target variable... with my limited swift knowledge I think thats what the problem is. So because of the limitation I dont know how to write a bridge class between ugh